# vscode, python, jupyter - NameError: name 'null' is not defined

Tags: python, jupyter, environment

When trying to run a cell in a Jupyter notebook in vscode, I get the following text:

```
... in <module>
    "execution_count": null,
NameError: name 'null' is not defined
```

This is resolved only when using "run all", which is far from convenient.

Note: this happens when trying to run any cell, for example

```py
print("foobar")
```

```
>> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:"path"", line 14, in <module>
    "execution_count": null,
NameError: name 'null' is not defined
```

Comment: It's not possible to answer this question without seeing the code itself. Can you reduce your code to a minimal example to reproduce this issue, and then post the code?

Also, a hint is in the error itself: the code is trying to find a variable named null, but it can't find it. Could you be running a portion of the notebook which relies on another portion that defines necessary variables?

Comment: @Mr.Fegur updated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It looks like this caused by attempting to run the actual notebook file as Python code. Jupyter notebooks aren't Python code - they're JSON files, which need to be interpretered by a rich editor. JSON is mostly compatible with Python dict literals, so trying to run it as Python "works" for a little bit, up until the first appearance of `null`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue for quite some time now.
What I ended up doing for resolving the problem was to reassign my keybindings as they seemed to be messed up.
Actually "Executing" the cell is different from running it.

Executing it didn't cause me any troubles actually, it only was the "Run Cell" which was broken, that I was personally calling using the ctrl + enter binding (in VS Code).

Changing this binding to execute cell removed this problem all entirely.
You can access the bindings remapping menu via File>Preferences>Keyboards Shortcuts.